# Find unique max values in data.frame by row also when two or more

Tags: r, dataframe, find, max, rows

I have several data.frames and I have to find the max value given a certain column. Some data.frames have a unique max value but others have two or more unique max values.

How can I print the rows with max values of such data.frames?

Some fake data:

```
#### Simple case with only one unique max value
df = data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2), y = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9))

df = data.frame(table(df$y))
df$Var1 = as.numeric(levels(df$Var1))[df$Var1]

max_val = df[which.max(df$Freq),]

print(max_val)
Var1 Freq
2   10    7

#### Unknown case with two unique max values
df_2 = data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2), y = c(10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11, 15))

df_2 = data.frame(table(df_2$y))
df_2$Var1 = as.numeric(levels(df_2$Var1))[df_2$Var1]
```

Desired output from `df_2`

```
  Var1 Freq
1    9    3
2   10    3
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select where the Freq is the same as the max

```
df_2[df_2$Freq == max(df_2$Freq),]

#  Var1 Freq
#1    9    3
#2   10    3
```